# Appending consecutive equal values to a list in python

Tags: python

So, I'm working on a python script that will take a list of integers (S), and output a list of lists based off of the integers in S, and the sum of each list must be the same value.

I'm having a problem with appending values that are the same. Python seems to be aggregating them as the same value, when I want it to create another entry.

I've tried using .extend with the same results. Also, I've read up and seen posts about multipling by a constant to create multiple values. The problem here is that I don't know how many times I will be adding the element. Is there an easy solution to this? Sorry if this has been answered before, but I can't find it.

```
    import itertools

    def arrangeBoxes(stacks, arr):
        perms = itertools.permutations(arr)
        total = sum(arr)
        stackSize = total / stacks

        if (not(stackSize.is_integer())):
            return [False, []]

        for i in perms:
            tempSum = 0
            tempArr = []
            stackArr = []
            built = False

            for j in i:
                tempArr.append(j)

                if (sum(tempArr) == stackSize):
                    stackArr.append(tempArr)
                    tempArr = []

                    if (j == i[len(i) - 1]):
                        built = True
                        break
                else:
                    if (j == i[len(i) - 1]):
                        break

            if (built):
                return [True, stackArr]

        return [False, []]

    # Doesn't Work.
    # Output: [True, [[3]]]
    # Should be: [True, [[3], [3], [3]]
    print(str(arrangeBoxes(3, [3, 3, 3])))

    # Works fine. 
    # Output: [True, [[2, 1], [2, 1], [3]]]
    print(str(arrangeBoxes(3, [2, 1, 2, 1, 3])))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you're explicitly breaking and returning when

```
j == i[len(i) - 1])
```

In the first iteration (of `(3,3,3)`) `j`, is obviously 3, and any cell in `i` is obviously 3 - this will be immediately True and break, then return.

Iterate over indices, if you want to check if you're in the last **index**, not over the element:

```
for perm in perms:
    ...
    for j in range(len(perm)):
        ...
        if j == len(perm) - 1:
            return [True, stackArr]
```

No need for `else` or `break`.

Comment: Ugh, what bad logic on my part. Thank you for pointing it out!

Comment: @mdx97 We all had them. Even worse. Keep it up.